# Did Vince Gironda eat, or encourage people to eat, raw egg whites?

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition

It’s my impression that he advocated drinking raw eggs, but someone pointed out to me that the Gironda method didn’t involve drinking the whites.

What was Vince Gironda’s habits around consumption of eggs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems he consumed the entire egg, mixed into half-and-half. From *The Wild Physique*:

> Nutrition for the bodybuilder is actually very simple. The bottom line is to get your system in positive nitrogen balance. This is achieved by ingesting 30-50 grams of grade-A protein every three hours to keep your blood-sugar level with a constant supply of protein to the muscles. Since raw fertile eggs are the number-one source of grade-A protein (and the least expensive) and are quickly and easily digested in a mixture of half & half, it is the best food source for growth and strength.
>
> This diet will provide a satisfied feeling in the hard gainer because of the steady bloodsugar levels. It is superior to a meat, egg, and water diet because you will never experience actual hunger or weariness. Since it puts you in a positive nitrogen balance (anabolic state) by precursing hormones, it is the best nutrition program for the hard gainer. It is also known as the ultimate muscle-building diet!